# Monaco Editor - Adding monarch multi-line string token for Lua

Tags: lua, token, monaco-editor

So i'm creating a 'lua' tokenizer using Monarch and Monaco editor, I have the basic variables and stuff setup, but the only problem is I have no idea how to add a multi-line string.

I see they did it with their own monaco but that is using the same character which is `
however for lua to create a multi-line string you need to use `[[` and close it with `]]`

Image of javascript multiline in their example.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zM9i.png

This is (from my understanding) the tokens they used in Monarch

```
// strings
[/`/, 'string', '@string_backtick'],

string_backtick: [
    [/\$\{/, { token: 'delimiter.bracket', next: '@bracketCounting' }],
    [/[^\\`$]+/, 'string'],
    [/@escapes/, 'string.escape'],
    [/\\./, 'string.escape.invalid'],
    [/`/, 'string', '@pop']
],
```